# $ \sin{x}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}\ +\ \frac{1}{3}\sin{3x}\ +\ \frac{1}{4}\sin{4x}\ =\ \frac{2}{3}\left(\cos{x}+1\right)\left(\sin^5x\ +\ 4\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**SORRY IF MY TITTLE IS UNCLEAR WITH ONLY MATH FUNCTIONS. IT'S MORE THAN 150 CHARACTERS**

- This is my math problem

$$ \sin {x}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\sin {2x}\ +\ \frac{1}{3}\sin {3x}\ +\ \frac{1}{4}\sin {4x}\ =\ \frac{2}{3}\left(\cos {x}+1\right)\left(\sin ^5x\ +\ 4\right) \left(*\right)
$$

- This is my effort

$$ \left(*\right) <=> 12\sin {x\left(1+\cos x\right)\ +\ 12\sin {x}\ -\ 16\sin ^3x\ +\ 12\sin {\left(x\right)\cos {\left(x\right)}\cos {\left(2x\right)}}}\ =\ 8\left(\cos x\ +\ 1\right)\left(\sin ^5x\ +\ 4\right)
$$

$$   <=> 12\sin {x\left(1+\cos x\right)\ + 4\sin {x\left(2\cos {\left(2x\right)\left(1+\cos {x}\right)\\ +\ \left(1+\cos {x}\right)\left(2\cos ^2x\ -\ 2\cos {x\ +\ 1}\right)}\right)}}\ =\ 8\left(\cos x\ +\ 1\right)\left(\sin ^5x\ +\ 4\right) 
$$

$$ <=> 4\sin {x\left(1+\cos {x}\right)\left(6\cos ^2x\ -\ 2\cos {x\ +\ 2}\right)\ =\ 8\left(\cos x\ +\ 1\right)\left(\sin ^5x\ +\ 4\right)}
$$

Now 
$$\cos {x} = -1
$$

or
$$ 6\sin {x}\cos ^2x\ -\ 2\cos {x}\sin {x}\ +\ 2\sin {x}\ -\ 2\sin ^5x\ -\ 8\ =\ 0 
$$

To here I tried many ways like converting all to \sin , group somes together but it didn't work. Please give me some **HINTS**

Comment: What's the source of the problem? Is it some identity to be established or an equation ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That's the source of the problem and I got stuck at the final step

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's an equation

Comment: Problems like these should always be solvable by using $\sin(x)=\Im(\exp(ix))$ and $\cos(x)=\Re(\exp(ix))$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch sorry , i didn't really understand your functions. Could you explain in trigonometric way

Comment: @ViệtAnh See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch actually, i haven't learnt that yet. It beyond my school knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It remains to solve the following equation.
$$\sin{x}(3\cos^2x-\cos{x}+1)=\sin^5x+4.$$
We'll prove that
$$\sin{x}(3\cos^2x-\cos{x}+1)<\sin^5x+4,$$ which says that this equation has no real roots.

Indeed,
$$\sin{x}(3\cos^2x-\cos{x}+1)=\sin{x}(3(1-\sin^2x)+1)-\sin{x}\cos{x}\leq$$
$$\leq\sin{x}(4-3\sin^2x)+\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{2}=4\sin{x}-3\sin^3x+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now, let $\sin{x}=a$ and since $3\cos^2x-\cos{x}+1>0$ and $\sin^5x+4>0,$ we see that $a>0$

and we need to prove that
$$a^5+3a^3-4a+3.5>0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$a^5+3a^3-4a+3.5>3a^3+2\cdot1.75-4a\geq\left(3\sqrt[3]{3\cdot1.75^2}-4\right)a>0.$$
I used the following AM-GM:

> for non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ we have:
>   $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$ or
>   $$x+y+z\geq3\sqrt[3]{xyz}.$$

Here $x=3a^3$ and $y=z=1.75.$

Comment: how can we know that a>0 and could explain clearly about the final line. You use AM-GM on which group?

Comment: I know why a>0 now, thank you. But i didn't understand how can you use AM-GM

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg I understand everything now. Thanks for your support. Your Inequalities proving is so great.

Comment: Hope to receive more on your useful support in the future.

Answer (score 2):

An algorithmic approach for many of these problems can be:

You [can call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$. Then $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}$. Making this substitution your equation

$$6\sin(x)cos^2(x) − 2\cos(x)\sin(x) + 2\sin(x) − 2\sin^5(x) − 8 = 0$$

becomes a polynomial equation.

$$6(2t)(1-t)^2(1+t^2)^2− 2(1-t)(2t)(1+t^2)^3 + 2(2t)(1+t^2)^4−2(2t)^5 − 8(1+t^2)^5=0$$

With [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) we check that this polynomial doesn't have real solutions.

Comment: but the exponent is so high

Comment: it reach to the power of 10.

Comment: @ViệtAnh This is not an answer just for you and your specific problem, but for others as well.

Comment: @ViệtAnh And large numbers exist. What can we do? Your specific problem might have a solution in which the equation gets easily re-written as a product of a couple of squares, but making a small variation to it would make the factorization not work. Should a small variation stop you from solving this kind of problems. So, what I wanted to show you is a method that can solve a large variety of problems like this.

Comment: Expanding, the polynomial is $2 t^{10}-5 t^9+10 t^8-6 t^7+20 t^6+16 t^5+20 t^4-2 t^3+10 t^2-3 t+2$